# NumberOfSections not working with IUITableViewDataSource Xamarin

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement multi section tableview with single class(instead of creating separate class for tableview datasource and delegate) by using `IUITableViewDataSource` interface. But the `NumberOfSections` method is not getting called.
My view controller code looks like:

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController, IUITableViewDelegate, IUITableViewDataSource
    {

        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            tableView.WeakDataSource = this;
            tableView.DataSource = this;
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.     
        }

        public nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
        {
            return 5;
        }

        public nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return 4;
        }

        public UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("Cell");
            cell.TextLabel.Text = "Row " + indexPath.Row + "   Section " + indexPath.Section;

            return cell;
        }


    }
```

This is woking perfectly if I create a `UITableViewSource` subclass and assign like

```
tableView.Source = new TableSource();
```

What is wrong with the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The table is loaded only when u create an instance of TableSource.
Add this code to viewDidLoad

```
    table = new UITableView(View.Bounds); // defaults to Plain style
    table.Source = new TableSource(tableItems);
    Add (table);
```

Comment: but my table rows are ok and I am loading tableview from storyboard